# How object is getting generated in below code?

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to understand one java code. (Basic knowledge of Java)

Here its is

WordCountMapper Class

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        for (String word : line.split(" ")) {

            if (word.length() > 0) {
                context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));

        }

    }
```

Mapper Class

```
    package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience.Public;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability.Stable;

@InterfaceAudience.Public
@InterfaceStability.Stable
public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {
    public Mapper() {
    }

    protected void setup(Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }

    protected void map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value, Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(key, value);
    }

    protected void cleanup(Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }

    public void run(Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }
        cleanup(context);
    }

    public abstract class Context implements MapContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {
        public Context() {
        }

}
```

}

Main method class

```
    package com.company;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
if(args.length !=2){
System.err.println("Invalid Command");
System.err.println("Usage: WordCount <input path> <output path>");
System.exit(0);
}
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
}
```

My doubt is in WordCount class how Text value is coming into existance ? I mean its an object but where its getting generated, there is no sign in main method class to instantiate instance of Text class.

And what it means - , I have never seen this before creating class like in below format

```
public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>
{
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think you are asking two questions. And your code doesn't build due to syntax errors.

Comment: Your code is also unreadable because it's not properly indented.

Comment: @nicomp, May be it wont build up but here am trying to understand only how Text value came into existence ?

Comment: @JonyLinux for better or worse you have a very low probability of getting an answer if you post garbage code, even if you think that is not relevant to your question. The SO community expects some minimum level of dedication to the craft.

Comment: I have edited my code, I hope its well indented..!!

Comment: You're never executing the Job, so the Text object never comes into existence

Comment: @cricket_007, Then who's doing that ?

Answer (score 3):

The code you have pasted is meant to run using the [Hadoop MapReduce framework](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html).

Basically you have here three classes:

- The *WordCount* mapper which seems to split strings and write these to the Hadoop streaming context
- The *Mapper* class which is part of the Hadoop streaming libraries
- The *WordCount* driver which submits the job to the Hadoop cluster

Actually I would have expected a `WordCountReducer` class in your question, but that seems not to be there.

Any way: the text will "come to existence" by copying it as a file to your Hadoop cluster and must be on HDFS (Hadoop File System) before you run the job.

This line of code refers to one HDFS path:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
```

And regarding the question about the code:

```
public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>
```

These are generic types (see this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm) here) which have to be declared each time you subclass a mapper.

Your `WordCount` mapper actually subclasses this `Mapper` class and specifies the four types:

```
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
```

These are the correspondences:

```
KEYIN    = LongWritable
VALUEIN  = Text
KEYOUT   = Text
VALUEOUT = IntWritable
```

Comment: you mean to say, the Text object is instantiated by hadoop framework when we put the data into HDFS. Is it what you are trying to say ? Because text's object is holding the data which is in HDFS, but that object doesnt seems to be getting generated from main method class, so only thing left is Hadoop itself. Isnt it ?

Comment: Yes, you save the file in HDFS and then when the driver is executed it will connect to the Hadoop cluster which will retrieve the file from HDFS for you and make it available to your mapper. The Text object is instantiated by the Hadoop framework so to say.

Comment: This is not Hadoop Streaming code. Streaming reads from stdin and writes to stdout. This is regular MapReduce code

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop API creates the necessary classes.

You can optionally set an `InputFormat`, and that needs to be the same as the input  formats used by the class in the `setMapperClass` (the KEYIN, VALUEIN fields). Similarly, an output format is also set, and there's inputs and outputs for a Reducer.

The default format is `TextInputFormat` which reads `LongWritable, Text` key value pairs. The `InputSplit` class is responsible for reading the bytes off the FileSystem and creating the `Writable` classes which are passed to the Mapper.

Worth mentioning that nothing is created until you start the job like

```
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```